# My MVC SelectList not selecting even though object has selected = true?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, html-select, selectlist

I have a select list builder which populated a new select list from an Enum type and takes an enum value to be selected as a parameter.

It is then added to a DropDownList as below

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status",ViewBag.Status as SelectList,"Select Status..", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The problem is its not selecting when i load the view, I have checked on the functions output and i can see the correct value has the selected marker as shown below.
[image]

Though when my view loads i get this

[image]

I can't imagine where i am going wrong as everything look as i suspect it should except my view that is... ?!?!

This is the output in my browser

[image]

Update:
Swapping the DropDownList helper to

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status")
```

Does the trick but i loose my custom styling, which is required... Why is it not selecting on the other method?

Comment: Do you use custom dropdown list control?

Comment: No I'm just using the in built one, I will add the output to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some custom dropdown styles. And your real dropdown is hidden. Please take a look at the HTML aroud your dropdown.

If you find hidden **select** tag you should correct your styles for your custom dropdown.

Comment: hidden select tag, I'm not sure i follow you? I will add my output markup so you can see what i have. I am just using the Bootstrap styles if that has any relevance?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out what was has caused the issue, the fact my Html.SelectList had the same name as the ViewBag property which contained my custom SelectList result. Changing the ViewBag item name from Status to statuses and my Helper call to

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status",ViewBag.Statuses as SelectList,"Select Status..", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Did the trick! It must be some kind of naming conflict within the MVC conventions! I hope this helps anyone else who has the same issue as i have found a few questions online with similar problems and no solution!

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to provide field name whose value will be bind by Razor engine to dropdownlist for that you need to provide the property name that you want to bind in dropdown. Try this out

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status",ViewBag.Status("AccountId","AccountName") as SelectList,"Select Status..", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

where AccountId,AccountName is the property field inside `viewbag.Status` Where AccountName will be show in as text in page and AccountId will be bind as value.

In your case check `viewbag.Status` and put property name that exist in

Comment: If you look at how i bound the select list in the method screenshot above you will see that i do this while passing the correct values.

Thanks anyway though :)